# condition not working in angularJS controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
var today = new Date();
var dd = today.getDate();
var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!
var yyyy = today.getFullYear(); 

var currentdate = yyyy+','+mm+','+dd;
var appointmentDate=moment($scope.AppointmentsList[i].J).format('YYYY,MM,DD');
console.log(appointDate)
if (currentdate > appointmentDate ) {
    console.log('test')
    //  $scope.isFutureDate=true;
}
```

here currentdate  and appointmentDate  showing properly , but condition not working ?

Comment: you need javascript date objects for `currentdate` and `appointmentDate` seems like u having strings instead of ojects

Answer (score 0):

seems like your are using library moment js. therefore you dont have deal with javascript `Date` object OR `strings`

```
var currentM = moment();
var appointmentM =moment($scope.AppointmentsList[i].J);                
 if (currentM.isBefore(appointmentM)) {
  //  $scope.isFutureDate=true;
 }
```

Alternatively to shorten your code you can do

```
 if (moment().isBefore($scope.AppointmentsList[i].J)) {
  //  $scope.isFutureDate=true;
 }
```

full explanation of moment `isBefore` is [here](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/)

Note- please check the code for some typos i have directly typed it here

Note- make sure `$scope.AppointmentsList[i].J` is parsable by moment library

Comment: Now the condition working but its not affect in HTML button,  <button class="btn btn-danger"  
                            ng-click="cancelAppointment(appointment)" ng-show="isFutureDate" >Cancel</button>

Comment: your second problem needs to be accompanied by some more code. Ask a new question

Comment: if my answer here solved your specified problem. mark it as an answer AND / OR upvote